# Google Maps Store Locator Only Returning One Result

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, csv

I've got the Google Maps Store Locator set up successfully. It functions correctly and I've used the example CSV (medicare.csv) that's used on Google's example:

http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/panel.html

It works fine when I use the CSV file from Google but when I use my CSV file (in the same format but with less columns) it only shows one result on the map no matter how many are there. The ones I'm using for the test are:

"Fcilty_nam","Street_add","Locality","State","Postcode","Country","Ycoord","Xcoord","uuid"
"Kids Club","4530 Union Bay Place Northeast","Seattle","WA","98105","United States","47.6616626","-122.2931334","213"
"Head Shoulder Knees & Toes","12418 102nd Avenue","Edemonton","AB","T5N 0M1","Canada","53.5433006","-113.5371704","214"

And an example from the medicare CSV is:

"Fcilty_typ","State","Fcilty_nam","Shp_num_an","Shp_centre","Street_add","Locality","Postcode","Hrs_of_bus","Wheelchair","Display_wd","Fcilty_typ_2","Xcoord","Ycoord","uuid","result","Audio"
"MO","NSW","Queanbeyan","Shop 47","Riverside Plaza","131 Monaro Street","Queanbeyan","2620","09:00-17:00 Monday to Friday, excluding Public Holidays","YES","1.5","http://www.medicareaustralia.gov.au/public/claims/offices.jsp","149.23532000","-35.35248400","67","999",""

I unfortunately can't share the webpage I'm working with so I'm going to have to figure this out from within the code itself. I understand that there are less columns in my CSV but it appears the columns I didn't include are not required. Does anybody know why it would only return one result? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, as long as your CSV file is in the same format as the original (use only a text editor, not Excel):

- entries are "quoted"
- entries are delimited with a comma ","
- end of line is "/n"

If so and you're still having the same problem its likely your Xcoord and Ycoord need to be switched...an easy error given the format of the CSV file from the example.
Also, if removing columns note its essential to have an unique UUID for each entry.

Comment: That worked. Yeah that documentation is a little bit short on this. I realized that UUID is compulsory, which I wasn't aware of until now. That fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On the first test, you forgot the comma between `"uuid" "Kids Club"`. Make it `"uuid", "Kids Club"`.
On the second test, you forgot the comma between `"Audio" "MO"`. Make it `"Audio", "MO"`.

Comment: Don't feel bad. I did the same thing the other day, and couldn't figure out what was wrong. Go figure.

Comment: That's the formatting on this site.  If you go to edit the post, you can see that line-endings are used in that location.  I can't fix it either, as it's <10 chars worth of edit :/

Comment: That's the CSV styling though. uuid is the end of the line (as is audio). That signals the end of the line in CSV formatting...